# Not able to run PolkadotJS apps on local

Tags: polkadot-js, substrate-node-template

I tried to clone https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps and run on local. When I execute `yarn` or `yarn install`, I get below logs:

```
➤ YN0013: │ @polkadot/react-identicon@npm:3.4.1 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote registry
➤ YN0013: │ @polkadot/react-qr@npm:3.4.1 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote registry
➤ YN0013: │ @polkadot/networks@npm:12.2.1 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote registry
➤ YN0013: │ @polkadot/phishing@npm:0.21.3 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote registry
➤ YN0013: │ @polkadot/react-identicon@npm:3.4.1 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote registry
➤ YN0013: │ @polkadot/react-qr@npm:3.4.1 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote registry
➤ YN0013: │ @polkadot/rpc-augment@npm:10.7.1 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote registry
```

My node version is v19.4.0 and yarn version is 3.2.0. Can somebody please help me fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The logs you posted above are not error logs, but this is `yarn berry` informing you that you don't have those packages cached (probably because this is your first install), and will fetch them from the registry.

After you `yarn install` you need to run `yarn start` or `yarn start:electron` in order to run polkadot-js/apps locally.

Comment: It is still not working. When I execute `yarn run start`, it says

`Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1741:`

There is no process on my system running on 3000. I also restarted my system. Is there any way to change port? Or I am missing anything?

Comment: Just to ensure when you run `lsof -i :3000` you get no output? And yes there is most certainly a way to change the port. Inside of `packages/apps/webpack.serve.cjs` you can change the `devServer` port.